# NSPredicate for one-to-many relationship give duplicate results

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

[image]I have 2 entities (Category and SubCategory) with a one to many relationship. I want to show categories in the tableView with each category represent one section in tableView (Category name will be the title of header view and all its associated subCategories will be the rows). I have to exclude the subcategories with 'isActive == NO'.
To achieve this I created NSFetchRequest on Category entity as below.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY subCategories.isActive == YES"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

But this fetch request gives multiples(Duplicate) Categories. i.e If total subCategories with "isActive == YES" is 25, I'm getting 25 Categories in the fetchedResult.

I also tried with "SUBQUERY", and with this I'm not getting duplicated categories but I'm getting all the SubCategories irrespective of "isActive == YES".

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(subCategories, $x, ($x. isActive == 1)).@count != 0)"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

Can any one help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Quick question: If you remove the predicate, do you get duplicate? I'm wondering (since if I'm not mistaken that you predicate should do the trick) if you didn't saved various `Category` entities without checking if it was already in DB.

Comment: @larme If I removed the predicate I'm not getting any duplicate results.

Comment: Are you using a NSFetchedResultsController? How is it set up?

Comment: @MartinR I'm not using NSFetchResultsController, using performBlock on MOC.
[moc performBlock:^{
                NSError *fetchError = nil;
                NSArray *fetchResult = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchError];
            }];

Comment: Then how do you display the entries in sections?